# Updating A textview from Wear Listener Service

Tags: android-activity, android-service, textview, android

I am trying to get the sensor information from android wear and I am using wearlistene service to do that!. What is the best way to update the UI like a simple textview to show that information in an another activity. Looks like a simple task but i have tried using Async Task which runs only once which doesn't suit me , threads and runonUithread those doesnt help since it blocking the service to run and they are not synchronous.

PS: Feel free to edit the question if I am wrong in the way I am asking It.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Using a broadreciever to update the UI and Broadcast service to send the values!! This did the trick